# Correct approach when mapping JSON with a lot of unnecessary information to a Java object

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping

So I have this quite big JSON string with a lot of nesting which I receive as a response to a call to a REST API and I want to map it to an object in my java application (currently using Jackson for that purspose). The problem is, I need maybe 50% of the information provided in that JSON string and the rest is simply unnecessary. What is the correct approach when modelling the class the JSON string should be mapped to? Should I just create only the fields I need in my objects and tell the mapper to ignore the rest?

And if so, what to do about the nesting? Let's say I need to get 1 field from but the construction looks like this:

```
{
   "abc":123,
   "bcd":"qwe",
   "cde":"asd",       
   "def":1,
   "obj":{          
      "av":861,
      "asdf":{
         "id":139204,                       
         "params":{
            "item":139070,
            "level":110
         }
    }
}
```

And I need to get the "level" property - should I recreate all the nesting with some sort of wrappers or is there more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Full example:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"abc\": 123,\n" +
                "  \"bcd\": \"qwe\",\n" +
                "  \"cde\": \"asd\",\n" +
                "  \"def\": 1,\n" +
                "  \"obj\": {\n" +
                "    \"av\": 861,\n" +
                "    \"asdf\": {\n" +
                "      \"id\": 139204,\n" +
                "      \"params\": {\n" +
                "        \"item\": 139070,\n" +
                "        \"level\": 110\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        MyObj obj = mapper.readValue(json, MyObj.class);

        System.out.println(obj);

    }

    public static class MyObj {
        private String bcd;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyObj{" +
                    "bcd='" + bcd + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

        public String getBcd() {
            return bcd;
        }

        public void setBcd(String bcd) {
            this.bcd = bcd;
        }
    }
}
```

It will print:

> MyObj{bcd='qwe'}

So, you may just play around with defining your object with needed nesting.

If you define objects with this way:

```
 public static class MyObj {
        private String bcd;
        private NestedObj1 obj;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyObj{" +
                    "bcd='" + bcd + '\'' +
                    ", obj=" + obj +
                    '}';
        }

        public String getBcd() {
            return bcd;
        }

        public void setBcd(String bcd) {
            this.bcd = bcd;
        }

        public NestedObj1 getObj() {
            return obj;
        }

        public void setObj(NestedObj1 obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
        }
    }


    public static class NestedObj1 {
        private NestedObj2 asdf;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "NestedObj1{" +
                    "asdf=" + asdf +
                    '}';
        }

        public NestedObj2 getAsdf() {
            return asdf;
        }

        public void setAsdf(NestedObj2 asdf) {
            this.asdf = asdf;
        }
    }

    public static class NestedObj2 {
        private int id;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "NestedObj2{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    '}';
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

The system will print:

> MyObj{bcd='qwe', obj=NestedObj1{asdf=NestedObj2{id=139204}}}

As you can see all unnecessary json values (that are not defined in the mapper classes) are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend in such cases to convert your nested json string into the corresponding flat json string.

This would help you avoid looping in JSONObject.

The flattening of the nested json can be taken care by using the below mentioned JSONFlattener API available in maven project.
Follow link: https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener

Approach:
Step 1 : Flatten your nested JSON using the mentioned API.
So in your case it would transform to something like :

```
{
   "abc":123,
   "bcd":"qwe",
   "cde":"asd",       
   "def":1,
   "obj.av":861,
   "obj.asdf.id":139204,
   "obj.asdf.params.item":139070,
   "obj.asdf.params.level":110
}
```

Now this simplified json keys can be mapped to the Java POJO.

Step 2: Now as per your requirement you can just put your required fields in your POJO and leave the other once which you want to ignore.
For this you can tell Jackson to ignore such fields? (non-existing on the POJO objects) using a class level annotation in your pojo class provided by Jackson.([JsonIgnoreProperties](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html)).

This should help you to simplify your solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When your Java representation diverges from the json, parsing directly into a class structure can be a poor fit. However, any well formed json can be parsed into a weakly typed map/list structure with relative ease. Ie with jackson:

```
Map jsonMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class);
```

We can use the Java 8 library [Dynamics](https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics) to help us deal with such structures in a null-safe & fluent way.

```
public class MyView {
    private final Dynamic data;

    public MyView(Map data) {
        this.data = Dynamic.from(data);
    }

    public String getBcd() {
        return data.get("bcd").asString();
    }

    public int getObjAsdfLevel() {
        return data.dget("obj.asdf.params.level").convert().intoInteger();
    }
}
```

In action:

```
int objAsdfLevel = new MyView(jsonMap).getObjAsdfLevel();
// 110
```

See https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics for the source/docs and more examples

Answer (score 0):

g,

If you're interested in switching to GSON, I have a library called [GsonPath](https://github.com/LachlanMcKee/gsonpath) which might suit your needs. The aim of the library is to provide an annotation processor that helps you flatten your POJO by generating the boilerplate code to you would normally need to write.

By using the library you can write a POJO similar to the following:

```
@AutoGsonAdapter
public class SamplePojo {
    int abc;

    String bcd;

    String cds;

    int def;

    @SerializedName("obj.av")
    int av;

    @SerializedName("obj.asdf.id")
    int asdf_id;

    @SerializedName("obj.asdf.params.item")
    int asdf_params_item;

    @SerializedName("obj.asdf.params.level")
    int asdf_params_level;
}
```

Then all you need to do in your `gson` object is to register a special `TypeAdapterFactory`

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(GsonPath.createTypeAdapterFactory());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

The documentation within the [library](https://github.com/LachlanMcKee/gsonpath) is faily comprehensive, let me know if you have any problems!